# Which jQuery transition plugin is used here?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I love the way [this site does transition between pages](http://digitalroadmap.com/).

Is the content being loaded via AJAX or is the browser actually opening the different pages when you click on the sections?

Because the links are being changed in the URL, how is it that they are maintaining transition between the sections ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery.address](https://github.com/asual/jquery-address) is being used for URL management and custom transitions for page change effects. (See http://digitalroadmap.com/js/functions.js `line 19` and below.)

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/ for various transition effects.

in your example `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` are used in custom `animate` transitions.